# Is reboot the only way to kill a process in "disk wait"?

Tags: ubuntu, kill

I occasionally get applications stuck on "disk wait" on FUSE filesystem due to network problem. They take up memory and their window is still around, so after some time I get a number of them  which is annoying. I googled around, and found some old [posts](http://www.sysadmintalk.com/showthread.php?threadid=485) saying that reboot the system is the only way to get rid of them. Is that still true?

Things I tried:

1. sudo kill -9
2. kill the parent process

Comment: What software are you using on top of FUSE? It is something standard or something you made yourself?

Comment: it's Fuse over NFS, not sure which implementation exactly, but googling for (FUSE "disk wait") shows that other people encounter this problem, ie http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.fuse.devel/month=20051001/page=4

Answer (score 1):

Either that, or fix the filesystem. If you don't want it to try an operation forever but would prefer it to fail with an I/O error after some amount of time, you should code it to do that. If you're using someone else's FUSE filesystem, there's a good chance that it has a mount option to permit soft failures, timeouts, or something similar.